# How to take the name of the column when use "apply" function to loop over the column

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe, which is

```
  SNP1 <- c("AA","GG","AG")
  SNP2 <- c("AA","CC","AC")
  SNP3 <- c("GG","AA","AG")
  df<- data.frame(SNP1, SNP2, SNP3)
  colnames(df)<- c('rs10000438', 'rs10000500','rs1000055')
```

With this dataframe `df`, I want to apply the function  `dominant_dummy` to each column. I use the `apply` function, but I found that for the `apply` function, when it loops over the column of a `dataframe`, it only extract a `vector` of this column values, not including the name of that column. But in the function `dominant_dummy`, it requires to have the name of the column for  this syntax `NCBI_snp_query(names(x))` . How can I use the `apply` function at the same time I can extract the `name of the column` the function just loop over?

```
  library(rsnps)
  dominant_dummy<- function(x){

    SNP_lib<- NCBI_snp_query(names(x))
    NCBI_snp_query(names(x))

    SNP_min<- SNP_lib$Minor
    SNP_name<- SNP_lib$Query

    SNPs=as.character(x)
    SNPs=as.factor(SNPs)



    check<-substr(levels(SNPs)[2],1,1)==SNP_min
    if(!check){
      levels(SNPs)<-c(0,1,1)
      SNPs<-as.numeric(as.character(SNP))
    }else {levels(SNPs)<-c(1,1,0)
    SNPs<-as.numeric(as.character(SNP))}
  }
  df_3levels<-apply(df,2, dominant_dummy)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function just isn't going to work with `apply` if you are going to require names. Since you basically require a data.frame to be passing in, you are going to have to do the slicing a bit more manually (assuming you don't want to change `dominant_dummy`)

```
df_3levels<-sapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) dominant_dummy(df[,i, drop=FALSE]))
```

Comment: Thank you. But I found that the function I define still does not work, and I found it is the problem of the levels() function. I create a new question regarding this which I can't solve. Could you help me to have a look? [How to apply Levels() function to a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809088/how-to-apply-levels-function-to-a-dataframe)